# Domain bound for IntVar in google or-tools produces Invalid model

Tags: java, constraint-programming, or-tools

I am using google or-tools in java.

```
CpModel model;
model = new CpModel();

IntVar[] var = new IntVar[3];
for (int i=0; i< 3; i++){
    var[i] = model.newBoolVar(String.format("var-%s",i));
}

IntVar sumVar = model.newIntVar(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, "sum");
model.addEquality(sumVar, LinearExpr.sum(var));

CpSolver cp = new CpSolver();
CpSolverStatus st = cp.solve(model);

System.out.println("solver status = " + st);
```

Above program prints "solver status = MODEL_INVALID"

But when I replace Long.MAX_VALUE with Long.MAX_VALUE-1 it prints "solver status = FEASIBLE"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [or-tools NewIntVar seems not supporting int64 in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61272596/or-tools-newintvar-seems-not-supporting-int64-in-python)

Comment: yes. Thanks @Stradivari